# How to expand multiple panels properly?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I am working with multiple panels and I added functionality to **expandAll/collapseAll** panels. My issue is:

**Lets say:**

1) I expand all panels

2) Now, I collapse **ONLY** the second panel

3) Now I click on the **ExpandAll button** (Expecting all panels to be expanded).

**Issue:** After following the above steps, I can't get the panels to expand.

Here's my code:

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zRjRYmP5wUCAJoR1cOvA?p=preview)

```
<button (click)="collapseAll()">ExpandAll</button>
<button (click)="expandAll()">CollapseAll</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems with this code:

1. You have just one property responsible for the collapsed state of every panel. This way it's impossible to control them separately.
2. You have one-way binding, so when your collapse the panels manually in your view, the model is not updated. I fixed your code and forked the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/rfiVj8vEIBDOZ8rIHV5i

The main ideas are:

Have dynamic template to keep your html dry:

```
<p-panel *ngFor="let panel of panels" 
          [header]="panel.name" 
          [toggleable]="true" 
          [(collapsed)]="panel.isCollapsed" <== notice the "banana-in-a-box" notation [()], which allows two-way binding
          [style]="{'margin-bottom':'20px'}">
    {{ panel.text }}
</p-panel>


export class AppComponent {

  panels = [
    {
      name: 'Panel 1',
      isCollapsed: false,
      text: `The story begins as Don Vito Corleone...`
    },
    {
      name: 'Panel 2',
      isCollapsed: false,
      text: `The story begins as Don Vito Corleone...`
    },
    {
      name: 'Panel 3',
      isCollapsed: false,
      text: `The story begins as Don Vito Corleone...`
    },
    {
      name: 'Panel 4',
      isCollapsed: false,
      text: `The story begins as Don Vito Corleone...`
    },
  ] // you can also move this to a separate file and import

  constructor() {
  }

  expandAll(){
    this.panels.forEach(panel => {
      panel.isCollapsed = false;
    });
  }

  collapseAll(){
    this.panels.forEach(panel => {
      panel.isCollapsed = true;
    });
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
If you don't want to extract the text from your panels you don't have to but in that case you won't be able to use *ngFor and you'll have to store the state of each panel in some datastructure of your component.

You can have somthing like this:

```
panelsCollapsed = [
    {
      isCollapsed: false,
    },
    {
      isCollapsed: false,
    },
    {
      isCollapsed: false,
    },
    {
      isCollapsed: false,
    }, // this can also be just an arry of booleans, I kep it as an object in case you want to add other fields to it
```

Then in your markup you'd have:

```
<p-panel header="Panel 1" [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="panelsCollapsed[0].isCollapsed" [style]="{'margin-bottom':'20px'}">
    The story begins as Don Vito Corleone...
</p-panel>
<p-panel header="Panel 2" [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="panelsCollapsed[1].isCollapsed" [style]="{'margin-bottom':'20px'}">
    The story begins as Don Vito Corleone...
</p-panel>
```

The methods for expanding/collapsing all would stay the same.

Comment: Is there a way to NOT extract the content of each panel and put it in the array? Basically, the content in my app is not simple text. Its actually a component and I don't want to do: text: MyComponent. Any ideas how to do it without extracting the text from each panel?

Comment: Cool! Good luck!